# Using Base2 with KnockoutJS View Models

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, radix

I am using Base2 as a means to allow us to easily do inheritance in our system, aswell as using KnockoutJS for some UI interactions.

We have defined a base class for our ViewModels

```
BaseViewModel = Base.extend({
    ...
});
```

Which we then extend for our view models:

```
ExampleViewModel = BaseViewModel.extend({
    text: ko.observable("")
});
```

However there seems to be a problem. When you create 2+ instances of the view model (say if you are pushing them in to an observableArray and using templates to build up a UI) it seems like any changes made to a bound field, updates all view models rather than just the one it's bound to.

Does anybody know why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the extension is not actually instantiating a new observable, its just copying the reference.

I think you can do something like this:

```
ExampleViewModel = BaseViewModel.extend({
    constructor: function() {
        this.text = ko.observable("");
    }
});
```

Not as nice though as normal Base2 syntax, but just a limitation in how Knockout is implemented due to issues with properties.